# Can I use AVS Device SDK to access another voice service API?

Tags: apache-2.0

We are developing a smart device in China and we would like to use DuerOS as our voice assistant. Since they have a version of API which is fully compatible with the Alexa Voice Service APIs, we want to re-use the [AVS Device SDK](https://github.com/alexa/avs-device-sdk) to access their AVS-compatible API to reduce our development effort.

However, I am not sure if there's any legal risk to do so, even if the SDK is using Apache License 2.0. Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of legal risks are you thinking about? As written, your question seems awfully broad and might be more suited for [law.se].

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Simply put, I want to know if I can use Alexa Device SDK as a SDK for another voice service in commercial use?